# Will Ubuntu 22.04 Carry GTK4?

Tags: gtk, gtk4

I am not sure if Ask Ubuntu is the right place for this question, or if I should be asking this at https://discourse.ubuntu.com/, but I am looking ahead to the next LTS release and hoping that it will contain GTK4. I develop GTK applications and there was a bug that existed in GTK 3.22.30 (highest release for Ubuntu 18.04) where pulsing on GtkProgressBar didn't work correctly. This was later patched in GTK 3.24 which is available for Ubuntu 20.04, but I do not want to have to update customers computers from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 20.04 and then inevitably again when I have to migrate everything from GTK3 to GTK4. I know that Ubuntu 22.04 will have GNOME 40 Desktop, but I have not seen anything anywhere in regards to GTK4. If anyone has any updates regarding this it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: I did not ask this question in regards to the availability of GTK4. It was intended more for what version of GTK that Ubuntu uses natively (available via apt-get upgrade). For example, the highest versions of GTK available for different LTS releases:

```
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS -> GTK 3.20.8
Ubuntu 18.04 LTS -> GTK 3.22.30
Ubuntu 20.04 LTS -> GTK 3.24.20
```

Comment: I think this question seems on-topic: To me, it seems a question about how the Ubuntu development cycle works. It's not a pre-release support question.

Comment: I agree with @user535733. Quoting from [Jorge's answer](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/872/816190) on [When are questions about "ubuntu+1" appropriate? - Ask Ubuntu Meta](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/871/816190): *"**Should be allowed:** Questions about features coming up in the release."*.

Comment: And i hope it will ship with current Gtk 4.6.1. 
In this early days it's important to switch 4.4 to 4.6 as it fixes some serious bugs. 
And 22.04 will be the base for snaps. Unfortunately there is no WebKitGtk for Gtk4 at the moment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ubuntu 21.04 already has GTK4 packages in addition to GTK3, and so does the upcoming 21.10.

Then, 22.04 would certainly have GTK4, but it is not possible to predict the version of GTK4 it would have.

| Release | GTK Version |
| --- | --- |
| Ubuntu 21.04 | 3.24.25, 4.0.3 |
| Ubuntu 21.10 | 3.24.29, 4.4.0 |
| Ubuntu 22.04 LTS | 4.6.2 |

You can check yourself at https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=gtk-4&searchon=names

However, you can aim for any recent version of GTK and publish your app through snap/flatpak.