# How to compile a GTK4 application in Ubuntu 21.10?

Tags: gtk, 21.10, pkg-config, gtk4

I am trying to compile a C GUI application using GTK4. I was previously told [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1361740/will-ubuntu-22-04-carry-gtk4) that both Ubuntu 21.04 and 21.10 would have both GTK3 and GTK4. However, when I installed Ubuntu 21.04 only GTK3 was present. I then did a dist-upgrade to 21.10 and found that both versions of GTK are native:

```
user@user: dpkg -l libgtk* | grep -e '^i' | grep -e 'libgtk-*[0-9]'
ii  libgtk-3-0:amd64           3.24.30-1ubuntu1 amd64        GTK graphical user interface library
ii  libgtk-3-bin               3.24.30-1ubuntu1 amd64        programs for the GTK graphical user interface library
ii  libgtk-3-common            3.24.30-1ubuntu1 all          common files for the GTK graphical user interface library
ii  libgtk-3-dev:amd64         3.24.30-1ubuntu1 amd64        development files for the GTK library
ii  libgtk-3-doc               3.24.30-1ubuntu1 all          documentation for the GTK graphical user interface library
ii  libgtk-4-1:amd64           4.4.0+ds1-5      amd64        GTK graphical user interface library
ii  libgtk-4-bin               4.4.0+ds1-5      amd64        programs for the GTK graphical user interface library
ii  libgtk-4-common            4.4.0+ds1-5      all          common files for the GTK graphical user interface library
ii  libgtk2.0-0:amd64          2.24.33-2ubuntu1 amd64        GTK graphical user interface library - old version
ii  libgtk2.0-bin              2.24.33-2ubuntu1 amd64        programs for the GTK graphical user interface library
ii  libgtk2.0-common           2.24.33-2ubuntu1 all          common files for the GTK graphical user interface library
ii  libgtk3-perl               0.038-1          all          Perl bindings for the GTK+ graphical user interface library
```

Just double checking the version of Ubuntu yields:

```
user@user: lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.10
Release:    21.10
Codename:   impish
```

The GTK [page](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/getting_started.html) says to use the following to compile a GTK4 app using `pkg-config`:

```
gcc $( pkg-config --cflags gtk4 ) -o example-0 example-0.c $( pkg-config --libs gtk4 )
```

This is very similar to previous versions of GTK. For GTK3 it was:

```
gcc $( pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0 ) -o example-0 example-0.c $( pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0 )
```

However, trying to compile the program using GTK4 results in:

```
user@user: make
Package gtk4 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk4.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gtk4' found
```

So then based on [here](https://superuser.com/questions/47967/where-does-pkg-config-takes-its-information-from) I ran:

```
user@user: pkg-config --variable pc_path pkg-config
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig
```

Searching all of those paths, I only find GTK related .pc files in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig` and I do not find anything for GTK4. I do find `gtk+-3.0.pc` there though. So my question is, if GTK4 is native to Ubuntu 21.10, why would the pkg-config files be missing? Where do I obtain them so I can compile using pkg-config?

ASIDE: I do not have enough reputation to create the `gtk4` tag. Could someone with enough reputation do so?

Comment: Do you have `libgtk-4-dev` installed? If not, install it with `sudo apt install libgtk-4-dev`

Comment: No, I did not, and that solved the problem. Not sure why that would be necessary when GTK4 was present on the OS without me downloading it.

Comment: It was not present, it is available in the repositories to be downloaded (just as, the KDE desktop is available in the repositories, but most likely you don't have it installed). It is not present by default because a very few percentage of users (only those who develop GTK4 apps) will require it.

Comment: I created the gtk4 tag.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will need to install `libgtk-4-dev`, with the command

```
sudo apt install libgtk-4-dev
```